# If condition being ignored in a loop to send emails from sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[This is the sheet I am using](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d8KHM1dDPXeAipjtIa7ks55AWaCNp5K8AP0MpK4UmDg/edit#gid=1451036760).

I am trying to send emails automatically for each employee on the Quota Capacity Recommendation form if Difference in Demand & Production is above 10 or below -10.

When I run the script the emails get sent even if the value is within the acceptable range (-9 to 9).

```
function checkValue() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Quota Capacity Recommendation");
  var num = sheet.getRange(2, 11).getValue(); //number of employees

  for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) { //loop to get each employee
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Quota Capacity Recommendation");
    var dif = sheet.getRange(i, 10).getValue(); //value to check
    var rc = sheet.getRange(i, 9).getValue();
    var name = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();

    if (dif > 10 || dif < -10) //condition
    {
      //GmailApp.sendEmail("user@domain.com",name+ " Quota Recommendation", name+ " has recommended quota change of " +rc);
      GmailApp.sendEmail("otheruser@domain.com", name + " Quota Recommendation", name + " has recommended quota change of " + rc);
      //MailApp.sendEmail("differentuser@domain.com",name+ " Quota Recommendation", name+ " has recommended quota change of " +rc);
    }
  }
}
```

---

Comment: I belive since the values in F and G are based on division the value may be something like 10.0001 which will pass one or the other test.  You could use Math.floor(value) to get it rounded down to an interger and then check the value.  Then you could also simpy use dif != 10.

Comment: Why not `if (Math.abs(dif) < 10) {`? Then you can be sure people (those who come after you, including you) understand that only the magnitude matters. You should also make sure a clear problem statement is identified, with example input that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(dif>10 || dif<10)
```

if bigger than 10 or less than 10. So that is !=10.

Answer (score 1):

It looks that the problem is that the values of column 10 (J) are percentages (the sample value es 20%) instead of integers 20.

You should have to change the value entered to be integers or the script tu use .1 instead or 10.